# Does reading a struct type column as string in spark can corrupt the data?

Tags: json, apache-spark, parquet

Assuming my dataset has 2 columns - id, input where id is of type Long & input a complex datatype like Struct & then i write it into an s3 bucket.

If i read back the data from this JSON/Parquet file in spark like this in below example - reading "input" as String instead of struct. Does the stringified JSON that i will read here can contain the corrupted "input" data? like loss in precision for floating numbers or order change in attribute of list or struct etc.

**How data written in the s3 -**

```
val inputStruct = StructType(Seq(
        StructField("price", DoubleType, nullable = true),
        StructField("color", StringType, nullable = true),
        StructField("marketplaces", ArrayType(StringType), nullable = true)
    ))
val structSchema = StructType(Seq(
        StructField("id", LongType, nullable = true),
        StructField("input", inputStruct, nullable = true)
    ))

    // Create a DataFrame with a struct column
val data = Seq(
        Row(1L, Row(10.52323309, "red", List("A","B", "C"))),
        Row(2L, Row(15.20929493, "blue", List("E","D", "F"))),
        Row(3L, Row(20.70923933, "green"))
    )
var df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), structSchema)
    df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json("s3://BUCKET_NAME/PREFIX/")
```

**How data is read back from s3 -**

```
val structStringSchema = StructType(Seq(
        StructField("id", LongType, nullable = true),
        StructField("input", StringType, nullable = true) //reading input column as string instead of struct
    ))
val inputDf = spark.read.schema(structStringSchema).json("s3://BUCKET_NAME/PREFIX/")
```